# Run 3 methods one after each other

Tags: objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to run 3 methods one after each other in a seperate thread that calls an api (NSURLSessionDataTask async). I have looked into dispatch groups but this seems to run method 1 and 2 at the same time and then runs method 3 when they finish:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

//METHOD 1
dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self method1WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

//METHOD 2
dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self method2WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //METHOD 3
});
```

I need it to run method 1 and when that completes run method 2, and when that completes finally run method 3 (queue the methods).

I know I could chain the methods on each completion to run the next but I thought there would be a better approach to this...any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong in calling [self method1]; [self method2]; [self method3]; ?

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo doing that will cause all of the 3 asynchronous tasks to happen immediately. He wants to call method 2 after method 1 completes, and method 3 after method 2 completes.

Comment: So wouldn't this work?
[self method1WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
    [self method2WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
        [self method3WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
        }];
    }];
}];

Comment: Yeah, it would, but he specifically said in the question that he didn't want to do that :) "I know I could chain the methods on each completion to run the next but I thought there would be a better approach to this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.

`dispatch_group_enter` and company only handle the bit that makes it so everything that `dispatch_group_enter`s into the `dispatch_group_t` will complete before calling the block passed into `dispatch_group_notify`.

So we can use them to good use when waiting for tasks. Rather than having just 1 group that waits for every task to finish, we can use a group for each asynchronous task that needs to be completed:

```
// You can get a global queue or create your own, it doesn't really matter
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
// Create a group for each task you want to wait for
dispatch_group_t group1 = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_t group2 = dispatch_group_create();

// Call your first task on the first group
dispatch_group_enter(group1);
[self method1WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
    // Task is completed, so signal that it has finished
    dispatch_group_leave(group1);
}];

// Call your 2nd task on the 2nd group
dispatch_group_enter(group2);
// Make the second task wait until group1 has completed before running
dispatch_group_notify(group1, queue, ^{
    // METHOD 2
    [self method2WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
        // Signal to the group that the task has completed
        dispatch_group_leave(group2);
    }];
});

// Nothing is waiting on the 3rd task, so no need to create a group for it
dispatch_group_notify(group2,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //METHOD 3
    // Do whatever you need to do in here
});
```

Here is some more information about [Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) and how you can use them.

Edit: Sorry, I completely changed my answer. Once you left your comment, it hit me that the tasks you were calling were asynchronous, and using a serial `dispatch_queue_t` would not make a difference! (The blocks are run serially, but method2 would be run immediately after method1, not wait for completion)

Comment: Thanks cjwirth, so on my method1WithCompletion calls would this still work with the serial queue or would it need tweaking too:

`NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{**
    //Handle data etc
});
});`

Comment: Please check: My first answer was wrong... It shouldn't matter what you have inside your `method1WithCompletion:` or `method2WithCompletion:`. Method 2 will be called whenever the completion block inside Method 1 is called, and Method 3 will be called when the completion block inside Method 2 is called.

Comment: Okay thanks for the updated answer. I will give this a go and let you know

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** *I don't think so anymore, **cjwirth** have refuted my assumption below in comments*

I think there still can be approach with [serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6) (But it's only supposition, I didn't check it). The main idea is to dispatch group's task into serial queue, with using `dispatch_group_enter(group)` before dispatch and `dispatch_group_leave(group)` on your method1..2 completes. Let me show what it's supposed to be:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

//METHOD 1
dispatch_group_enter(group);
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
   [self method1WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
   dispatch_async(queue, ^{                     
                     dispatch_group_leave(group);
             });
    }];
});

//METHOD 2
dispatch_group_enter(group);
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
   [self method2WithCompletion:^(BOOL success){
   dispatch_async(queue, ^{                     
                     dispatch_group_leave(group);
             });
    }];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    //METHOD 3
});
```

**NOTE:** This kind of implementation looks like something wrong. As we had NSOperationQueue already, so I would recommend you to wrap your `NSURLSessionDataTask`'s stuff into NSOperation and perform them sequentially

Comment: I was playing around with implementations like this, but it won't work. The problem is that the block passed into `dispatch_group_async` finishes almost immediately (it just sets off the async call to `method1WithCompletion`, it does not wait for the completion). So method 1 and 2 are called almost instantaneously, and 3 is called when they all are complete. I was using [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad17ae377b58002ec2d0) to test, and you can see that it does not work :(

Comment: On the same token, I think `NSOperation` would have the same problem of waiting for completion as GCD... I haven't used it that much, so I might be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, I've check your test code and you are completely right! As for `NSOperation`, in short, serial operation queue would not start next queued operation until previous is finished, and you can change operations's finish state when method1..2's completes. Also, operations have dependency to make them execute in appropriate order. Need to check this also. I will do some sample code later